# How does Altium Designer's "impedance constraint" feature work?

Tags: rf, pcb-design, impedance, altium, trace

Altium has a design rules option for setting a track width constraint according to line's impedance (e.g.; 50\$\Omega\$). How do I use it? Please give me instructions or a link to an online tutorial. Will this feature affect the default Interactive Routing track width setting when enabled?

Does Altium check line impedance in PCB editor, or should I use Signal Integrity utility for it?

(Note: My application is "GSM module with external antenna".)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **must** have at least one power/ground plane defined in your layer stack-up for impedance controlled routing to work. From [the docs](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Impedance-Controlled+Routing) linked by @danny:

> Defining the Layer Stackup
>
> A fundamental requirement for controlling the impedance is to include
>   power planes.

Basically, the calculations for microstrip or stripline traces require knowledge of the distance between the signal plane and the ground plane. Since you cannot have a plane as an external layer (this is a Altium restriction), you therefore must have a minimum stackup of three layers.

If you want to do two-layer impedance controlled layout, the best workaround right now is to add a third layer as a ground plane, specify the thickness between the signal plane and ground plane the same as your full 2-layer core thickness, and just either fill the bottom plane with a manual ground polygon and don't export the ground plane when generating gerbers, or export the power plane as a positive layer and ignore the bottom layer when you're generating gerbers.

Comment: "must have at least one power/ground plane defined in your layer stack-up for impedance controlled routing to work."
means the board at least 3 layers.so how to calculate or design a two-layer board impedance? @Connor Wolf because there has wires or components on the bottom layer. You add a third layer and how to set it as a ground plane? or just don't care? can you give me a screenshot of the layer set?

Comment: Add a ground plane, set the spacing between the ground plane and the outer layer to the same thickness as the entire board.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already viewed this page:
http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Impedance-Controlled+Routing

Comment: Yes, and it's didn't help at all. But i've solved my problem - altium couldn't calculate impedance on 2-layer pcb, 4-layer works well. Thanks for responding :)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.  It would help if you included a small portion of the page in your answer, to ensure it remains relevant if the link disappears.